# Change paths in all SQL databases after moving server and not using same path anymore

Tags: database, path

A lot of sql databases (one instance) connected to an app(accounting, many dossiers.).

Each dossier we open in the app, and work in, we can for example open a  booked invoice by clicking on the attachment button on the open Windows (open Dossier) .

Each file(invoice) that is opened is stored in a certain drive: let say  Z:\ foldername\subfolder\dossiername,...  X:\ foldername\documents\dossiername\filenam.pdf.

Now server is moved  and we stopped using several network drivers. there is now only one networkdrive, let say with letter Y

All the databases  stored the old path, witch means, If we click on attachment in the new server, it will not be able to find the file.

To change in the app each dossier manually to correct the path, will be possible but time as for eacht file the path must be changed (more then 10000 invoices)... .

Question

Is there a methode to use in SQL studio manager, or anything that can get the same goal: to correct all  paths in de databases, like in notepad: search and replace), so we can be sure all old network drives paths are corrected and are linked to the new networt path?

I did not yet tried any solution.

So we only need to spend time to prepare well  in sql to update paths (3 or 4 networkpaths ) to one network drive letter and including some subfolders if changed.  Then all links (more then 10000) automatically  will be updated, and button attachment will open the file... .

And not sure about the link configured in the app, if this also will change once the databases are upated? I asume the app configuration is stored in the database too or else in separate files so then notepad can do the trick for if thes paths (app) are in certains files.